# java multithreading make universal code using list with different size against number of cores

Tags: java, multithreading

We want to process List exList (which has a variable size) in parallel.

How could we make this  to work with different sizes of exList and minimum one core and max 4 cores ?

The given code assumes that exList.size > 40. (if size is < 40 se simply use one thread).

But all of that is hard coded. So - how can this code be enhanced to make parallel runs "dynamically"; dependent on the size of our list?

```
    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    final int start  = exList.size() / threads;

        try {

            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    for(int i =0; i < start;i++){

                            System.out.println(exList.get(i));

                    }
                }});
            t1.start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    for(int i =start; i < start * 2;i++){
                             System.out.println(exList.get(i));
                    }
                }});
            t2.start();

            Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    for(int i = start *2; i < start * 3;i++){
                            System.out.println(exList.get(i));
                    }
                }});
            t3.start();

            Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    for(int i =start * 3 ; i < exList.size();i++){
                            System.out.println(exList.get(i));
                    }
                }});
            t4.start();

        }catch (Exception e){

        }
```

Comment: You make this question work by **first** indenting/formatting it in a readable way. That preview window, and all the explanations for formatting exist for the reason that **you** want us to spend our time to help you. So **you** spend the 1 minute it takes to reasonable format your input to us.

Comment: Beyond that: read [mcve]. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I am so sorry  really . my english its bad  .  you can see that what i am implemeting its hard coded .   exList must be divided by numbers of cores to make threads . but exList.size() could be 100 or 47 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already computing the number of threads that might be good to use.

```
int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

But you are simply drawing the wrong conclusion from that! The idea of computing that `start` value only adds confusion; it doesn't give you anything meaningful. Instead, simply go for:

```
int listSize = exList.size();

for (int shardNumber = 0; shardNumber < threads; shardNumber++) {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      for(int listIndex = shardNumber*listSize; listIndex < (shardNumber+1)*listSize; listIndex++) {
        System.out.println(exList.get(listIndex));
      }
   }}).start();
}
```

In other words: you simply **slice** your `exList` into `thread` "shards". And then you create one thread to process such a shard/slice.

Please note: the above isn't tested. It is meant as idea to get you going! You want to **carefully** check my math to ensure that the inner loop is really fetching the correct elements!

And hint: avoid creating *threads* and starting threads on that low level. You better create an [ExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) and submit runnables. Use abstractions, not "low level" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
exList is a list of strings

final int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
final int listSize = exList.size()/threads + 1;
Thread[] t = new Thread[threads];

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {

    final int finalshardNumber = i;

    final int finalI = i;
        t[i] = new Thread() {
                public void run() {


                for(int listIndex = finalshardNumber * listSize; listIndex < ( finalshardNumber + 1) *listSize; listIndex++) {

             try {
                                     //thread // index of exList  //string from exList            
                 System.out.println( finalI +" "+ listIndex +"  "+ exList.get(listIndex));

             }catch (Exception e){


                 }

                  }


          }}; t[i].start();


  }
```